# How to show different view controller on did select of collectionv view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have 3 view controllers called `firstvc`, `secondvc`, `thirdvc`. And I have one collection view which will scroll horizontally. I have done that. And if I select any cell, it will print which index path it was. It's fine, no problem. So in my `mainviewcontroller` I have one collection view which will scroll horizontally. And there is one `UIView` called `myview`. Whenever I press any cell, I get its `indexPath`. I need to show my 3 view controllers as subviews of `myview` in my `mainviewcontroller`.

My code so far:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
         let alertStoryBoard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
         if let allCollectionViewController = alertStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"firstvc") as? firstvc {
             self.contentSubView.addSubview(allCollectionViewController)
         } else if indexPath.item == 1 {
            
         } else if indexPath.item == 2 {
            
         }
    }
}
```

I am getting error on this line :

```
 self.contentSubView.addSubview(allCollectionViewController)
```

`Cannot convert value of type 'firstvc' to expected argument type 'UIView'`

How do i solve this issues.

Thanks in advance !!

## UPDATED:

if indexPath.item == 0 {

```
    let alertStoryBoard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    
    
    if  let allCollectionViewController = alertStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"firstvc") as? firstvc  {
        
       
        
          self.contentSubView.addSubview(allCollectionViewController.view)
        

    
    
} else if indexPath.item == 1 {
        
        
        let alertStoryBoard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        
        
        if  let allCollec = alertStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"secondvc") as? secondvc  {
       
            self.contentSubView.addSubview(allCollec.view)

    
}else if indexPath.item == 2 {
       
            let alertStoryBoard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            
            
            if  let wController = alertStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"Thirdvc") as? Thirdvc  {
       
                self.contentSubView.addSubview(wController.view)

}
```

Only showing first vc class alone, not showing second and third one. Also, why i am following lk this means. When ever i press on any collection view cell, that particular class view controlelr have to show in my sub view of uiview in my `mainviewcontroller`

In my first view controller i placed one uiview with some background color .But that not at all showing .Its showing whitee color.That too not showing correctly

Comment: use like `self.contentSubView.addSubview(allCollectionViewController.view)`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik   please see my updated post

Comment: set the frame based on your myview

Comment: Means, should i need to add that frames in my first vc or where...plz tell me with some code solution

Comment: can you add some UI what type of OP you expect

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i am not getting any image like my expect. I will clearly explain. in my view controller i have to populate like dynamic items like `milk,sand,wood, etc.`. And below i have one uiview with round corner border. i have all view controllers for the respective items. When ever i selct any item, that view controller have to display inside my uiview in my mainviewcontroller

Comment: ok I partially I understand, I add my answer , if we are in the correct way guide me

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  if u want i can shar my demo project to u

Comment: check the updated answer once , if it is not successful, attach your project I will check

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik   my proejct zip https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwj745kdgqvgjxa/Collection%20view%20example.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
// handle tap events
print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")

    based on your comment remove the subviews before add on your myview

    for subview in contentSubView.subviews {
          subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    let alertStoryBoard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var controller: UIViewController!

if indexPath.item == 0 {

    if  let allCollectionViewController = alertStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"firstvc") as? firstvc  {

        controller = allCollectionViewController
      }

} else if indexPath.item == 1 {

        if  let allCollec = alertStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"secondvc") as? secondvc  {
       controller = allCollec
       }


}else if indexPath.item == 2 {


            if  let wController = alertStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"Thirdvc") as? Thirdvc  {
       controller = wController
    }

}

   addChildViewController(controller)

 // Add the child's View as a subview
  contentSubView.addSubview(controller.view)
  controller.view.frame = contentSubView.bounds
  controller.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

  // tell the childviewcontroller it's contained in it's parent
   controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

Comment: for ur reference my project zip https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwj745kdgqvgjxa/Collection%20view%20example.zip?dl=0

Comment: i will check the above one solution too

Comment: @spikesa - my answer will work , I checked the sample project

Comment: @spikesa - download the updated project from here https://www.sendspace.com/file/mhkuff

Comment: yeah, but one doubt..is its possible like..if i swipe the `contentSubView` to right or left, the particular next viewcontroller also have to display same my colelction view cell also have to highlight based on the view was present under contentSubView

Comment: @spikesa - ha ha, everything is possible, use Swipe Gesture for your concept

Comment: @spikesa - are you checked the answer, I think your problem is solved, i am waiting for your reply

Comment: sorry internet issue was ter..Yes its worked..But i tried for Swipe Gesture..but i dont know how to applay there to swipe the view controllers as well as the cell highlight

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik...if possible can u help me on that with that swipe geture on that same proejct zip ??.that will be helpfull

Comment: @spikesa - sorry bro, I have a work , I  will try else try once if you not get the answer call here bro

Comment: okay thanks.But, i already tried now. BUt dont knwo how to use that to swipe left and right of uiviewcontroller as well as the collection view cell highlight

Comment: i tried to create the swipe guester. But i am not getting exactly. When u free can u help me with my project zip...It will b helpfull man.

Comment: @Anbu.Kathick.  Are you available

Comment: @Anbu.Karthick  the same project zip that u have know. Same thing only..Thsnk you

Comment: sorry for late replay,You have sent me know same only. I just  create swipe guster programatixally.but dont knwo hoe to keep..u can take that project and do that solution man

Comment: @Anbu.Karthick   Any solution please.. I need to swipe left and right at the same time my collection view cell also have to swipe and highlight. For example, if  am in `firstvc` then my first cell will be highlight. Then if i swipe right then my `secondvc` data have to come at teh same time my second collection view cell have to b highlight.  Ths is what i tried...but not able to achive....can i post new question for this ?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthk  here that project anbu  https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwj745kdgqvgjxa/Collection%20view%20example.zip?dl=0

Comment: brother, Have you got that..Sorry for asking again..that issues is little bit urgent , form past 2 days i looking that..not able to get that

Comment: Ayn solution brother.

Comment: if its not possible please let me know brother. i will see some other solution.please let me know any solution for that is posiblem

Comment: dropbox link is not active

Answer (score 1):

you can push present viewcontroller but you can't add viewcontroller as subview.

If you want to add as subview then you can do like,

```
  self.contentSubView.addSubview(allCollectionViewController.view)
```

or push viewcontroller if you have navigation controller like

```
 navigationController?.pushViewController(allCollectionViewController, animated: true)
```

or present it like

```
 present(allCollectionViewController, animated: true) { 

    }
```

Comment: @LionAny solution please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251141/swipe-left-or-right-to-load-the-view-controller-with-the-collection-view-cell-hi

Answer (score 1):

```
//Do this:

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

//You have to present your view controller and what you are doing is adding it as a sub view.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is very obvious. You can only use addSubview according to this definition:

```
open func addSubview(_ view: UIView)
```

If you want to use multiple view controllers in one view controller, I would recommend using container view controllers.

Try this tutorial: https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/

Otherwise a simple approach is to use:

```
self.contentSubView.addSubview(allCollectionViewController.view)
```

You can then use constraints on the view to manage multiple view controllers.