# ViewController don't launch

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a problem.
When I select `cell` of `UICollectionView`, I must go to next `ViewController`, but it not works.
`NavigationController`, pushed `ViewController`, my `object` are initialized, but I stay at current controller
[image: ScreenShot1]
What goes wrong?
Why NavigationController after pushing don't know about RoomViewController? it's absent in ViewControllers list:
[image: ScreenShoot2]
StoryBoard screenshot:
[image: ScreenShot3]
initial ViewController, which push MainViewController code:

```
func showMainViewController(house: NLHouse) {
        let mainController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as? MainViewController
        if let mainController = mainController {
            mainController.house = house
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainController, animated: true)
            print()
        }
    }
```

MainViewController, which push RoomViewController code:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var devicesCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var house: NLHouse?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print()
        devicesCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

}

extension MainViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return house?.rooms?.count ?? 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let roomCell = devicesCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "roomCell", for: indexPath) as? RoomsCollectionViewCell
        if let roomCell = roomCell, let rooms = house?.rooms {
            roomCell.setRoomInfoInCell(room: rooms[indexPath.item])
        }
        return roomCell ?? UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let roomController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RoomViewController") as? RoomViewController, let rooms = house?.rooms {
            roomController.room = rooms[indexPath.item]
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(roomController, animated: true)
            print()
        }
    }
}
```

push code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let roomController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RoomViewController") as? RoomViewController, let rooms = house?.rooms {
            roomController.room = rooms[indexPath.item]
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(roomController, animated: true)
            print()
        }
```

pushed class code:

```
import UIKit

class RoomViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var roomNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var devicesCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var room: NLRoom?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let room = room {
            if let roomName = room.roomName {
                roomNameLabel.text = roomName
            }
            devicesCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

extension RoomViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return room?.devices?.count ?? 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let deviceCell = devicesCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "deviceCell", for: indexPath) as? DevicesCollectionViewCell
        if let deviceCell = deviceCell, let devices = room?.devices {
            deviceCell.setDeviceInfoInCell(device: devices[indexPath.item])
        }
        return deviceCell ?? UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: Post code not images.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and step through your code?  There are a number of conditional statements that could be false.

Comment: Hope this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237221/how-to-show-different-view-controller-on-did-select-of-collectionv-view-cell

Comment: @Paulw11 I continue after breakpoint, I use it for checking code

Comment: @FaysalAhmed it's different with my problem

Comment: @SergeyHleb, `UINavigationController` what you push from is not that containing your viewController with tableView. Check your hierarchy.

Comment: @Sergey Hleb, put your pushing code in DispatchQueue.main.async { } and check once.

Comment: @SergeyFedorov, I know, but I set action for select item - push ViewController, why it's not push?

Comment: @Rohi, isn't working

Comment: Sergery do you get any warnings/errors in the console? @Rohi just to help for the future reference. I think you mean "check again". "Once" means one time only.

Comment: @Sergey Hleb, what is the rootViewController of the navigationController you use?

Comment: @SergeyHleb what means “i know”? Try this: push your controller, then enter “View hierarchy” tool and inspect which controllers/navigation controllers are presented.

Comment: @Scriptable, No, warnings/errors are absent. I understands what Rohi means

Comment: @Rohi, It's another ViewController, from which I goes to that ViewController

Comment: I understood what he meant too, just trying to help improve

Comment: @ Sergey Hleb, Is that another viewController is presented or pushed?

Comment: @Rohi, it's presents, when app launches, but after it's push current ViewController.

Comment: @ Sergey Hleb, So anotherViewController is the presented controller from your naviagtionController, above which you are pushing your currentController, which won't work.

Comment: @Rohi, No, root view controller push my current controller, which work, and my current controller have UICollectionView. if I tap on cell, I must go to RoomViewController

Comment: @ Sergey Hleb, add super.viewWillAppear(animated) in RoomViewController's viewwillappear and check again as per @Mukul More answer.

Comment: @Rohi, I trying yet, not succesfull

Comment: @ Sergey Hleb, are you creating naviagtionController programatically or through storyboard?

Comment: @Rohi, on StoryBoard

Comment: @SergeyFedorov, I checked, and edit my question. After pushing I check NavigationController's list of ViewController and not see my RoomViewController in it.

Comment: @ Sergey Hleb,  code repo you have on GIT?

Comment: @Rohi, No, I haven't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i see on your screenshot: you have viewController that is root for your navigation controller. Two additional view controllers: `main` and `room`.
Tell me, how you present your `MainViewController`?
I assume that you push your `MainViewController` from `ViewController` with creation new `UINavigationController` and setting `MainViewController` as root viewController for it. Then you try to push `RootViewController` from first `UINavigationController`. 
If you want your project work well - remove ViewController from storyboard, connect MainViewController instead it. This way, when you will push `RoomViewController` they will be in the same navigation stack with your `MainViewController`.
You need your stucture look like this:
[image]

Add your full project in zip file to investigate for sure.

**UPDATE:**
After reviewing suorce code of ViewController i found that `showMainViewController` method is being called from background (after receiving data from API). Dispatching push on main queue solved problem.
For future: anything you do with UI do in main thread.

Comment: No, I can't. In future, ViewController(my root ViewController) will perform other functions, and I will move from it to the MainViewController. From RoomViewController I will also switch to another controllers

Comment: @SergeyHleb share code of ViewControler. Answer is in it

Comment: I show method, which push MainViewController. Other methods in ViewController calls Manager for get data from API and create objects.

Comment: @SergeyHleb send me your project files in Telegram 'mussscat'

Answer (score -1):

Please add

```
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
```

as first line below function of RoomViewController

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
```

What is happening is you are instantiating the controller but when you push the viewWillAppear doesn't invoke the defined methods required for view to appear because super.viewWillAppear is not called.

or

It might happen that you the controller where you have called the below function is not itself in the navigation stack. Make sure the VC is part of a navigation controller's view controllers, then only this will be effective.

```
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(roomController, animated: true)
```

Comment: No, isn't working. after pushing I set breakpoint, and check controllers list of NavigationController, and my RoomViewController is absent in ViewControllers list

Comment: No, I haven't, but if need, I can send code in Viber, Telegram

Comment: I edited my question and add screenshot. After pushing I check NavigationController's list of ViewControllers and not see my RoomViewController in it. Why?

Comment: Can you add the code for how you are presenting or showing the first view controller where the push code is written?

Comment: @Rohi, Yes, but MainViewController isn't initial ViewController. initial View Controller is ViewController, and it push MainViewController, and MainViewController must push RoomViewController

Comment: Your initial view controller should be a navigation controller whose root view is your first/main view controller then you will be be able to push it and see it.

Comment: @Sergey Hleb, Can you add storyBoard screenshot in your question?

Comment: @Rohi, yes, complete

Comment: @MukulMore, I'm again edit my question and add StoryBoard screenshot, and code in initial ViewController class, which pushed MainViewController, and MainViewController's code. On StoryBoard screenshot Controllers places in order, how I push them

Comment: @Sergey Hleb, Is for RoomViewController class is set in storyBoard?

Comment: @Rohi, Yes, it have class RoomViewController and storyboard id RoomViewController

Comment: @Sergey Hleb, Make mainviewcontroller as rootviewcontroller and remove viewcontroller from your storyboard.